# Density of states; when states are discrete

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, density-of-states

Consider simple fermi Dirac distribution $f(\epsilon)$, where to get the total number of particles($T=0$), we need to do the following integration $\int_0^{e_f}f(\epsilon)\mathcal{D}(\epsilon)\,d\epsilon$. Where it is assumed that there are $\mathcal{D}(\epsilon)$ number of microstates available at each $\epsilon$. Now, this $\mathcal{D}(\epsilon)$ is actually the jacobian of momentum integration. For example, consider I have a 2D band structure so that $\epsilon(p_x,p_y)$, in this case total number of particle integration converted to $\int_{p\in{e_f}}f(\epsilon(p_x,p_y))\frac{dp_x\,dp_y}{(2\pi\hbar)^2}$, where the assumption is that $(2\pi\hbar)^2$ contains one microstate.

Here $f(p_x,p_y)$ is number of particle at state $(p_x,p_y)$. If I have a finite lattice with periodic boundary condition, then the number of states are discrete, not continuous. For simplicity, If I have only two states in the first Brillouin zone, then the total number of particles will be $f(p_x^1,p_y^1)+f(p_x^2,p_y^2)$. Now, the sum is not exactly equal to integration. The underlying assumption is that there exists only one microstate at each $(p_x,p_y)$ when I am doing the sum, but in the case of integration, the available microstates are not one but $\frac{dp_x\,dp_y}{(2\pi\hbar)^2}$. So when the lattice is actually an infinite lattice, then the discreetness of the states will be gone. It will become continuous, and so the sum should become an infinite sum, but it becomes integration.

I want to know how the sum is becoming integration here. Why should we assume in the case of infinite lattice that there is not only one microstate at each $(p_x,p_y)$ but $\frac{dp_x\,dp_y}{(2\pi\hbar)^2}$ number of states?